# Read XML File with Namespaces using xmlnamespaces in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery, xml-namespaces

After several days of tweaking i still couldn't get this right. I am trying to read a xml file with lots of namespaces, inserting particular node values to a different table.

**XML**

```
<ArrayOfCatalogItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CatalogItem Version="1">
    <Container xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <ContainerType>Unknown</ContainerType>
      <MarkedForRetail xsi:nil="true" />
    </Container>
    <Documents CultureCode="en" Elink="https://3eonline.com/ImageServer/ImageViewer.aspx?id=3Q%2ffAR8ne%2fvPh6syVnSymkS%2bBDo8OjmbVocxRCMEgeEuoz0WYqIq%2bpG3%2b3wu9B2vvARePPfTWFBb0hg91%2fRYfNzA43I%2baZTLYlibHjHcCDI%3d" Format="Msds" DocumentType="Sds" xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
    <Documents CultureCode="en" Elink="https://3eonline.com/ImageServer/ImageViewer.aspx?id=3Q%2ffAR8ne%2fvPh6syVnSymniD9dyO5cXo%2bPmAACkW7RMmVjYMZVxizRxXLlqcjbNGgyhjsG5gzhZK9bibPB5EPg%3d%3d" Format="ClientAttachment" DocumentType="Attachment" xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
    <IsHazardous xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">true</IsHazardous>
    <ManufacturerName xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">Sigma-Aldrich</ManufacturerName>
    <Msds xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <Elink>https://3eonline.com/ImageServer/ImageViewer.aspx?id=3Q%2ffAR8ne%2fvPh6syVnSymqIuIP5CInA01ZbaRQ9r18HUOi1FRQqntYtr58dWAm4wO3rdUO%2bO6MamuvwN7v7fbA%3d%3d</Elink>
      <FireCodeClassification>
      <MsdsId>8342624</MsdsId>
      <Properties>
        <PhysicalState>Liquid</PhysicalState>
        <BoilingPoint>
          <Minimum xsi:nil="true" />
          <Range>EqualTo</Range>
          <Units>Celsius</Units>
          <Value>217.0000</Value>
        </BoilingPoint>
      </Properties>
      <TransportationClassificationCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <WasteCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <ExtendedSds>false</ExtendedSds>
      <TransportationExceptionClassificationCompleted xsi:nil="true" />
      <BestAvailable>false</BestAvailable>
    </Msds>
    <ProductIdentifiers xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">
      <Identifier>4197644</Identifier>
      <FlaggedForResend xsi:nil="true" />
    </ProductIdentifiers>
    <ProductName xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">(3-Aminopropyl)triethoxyeilane - A3648</ProductName>
    <ProductUid xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">4d3dc6df9cf24cc6b3ab2b6be8373858</ProductUid>
    <IsDeactivated xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml">false</IsDeactivated>
    <DeactivatedDate xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml" />
  </CatalogItem>
</ArrayOfCatalogItem>
```

I need to fetch several values from this xml (I deleted most of the xml for readability). I wrote the sample query to fetch only Identifier and all i get is 'Null' for the column Identifier. I want to fetch ContainerType,MsdsID,PhysicalState,Minimum,

**Query**

```
DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE (XMLDATA XML)

INSERT INTO @XmlTable(XMLData)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\AAEWRXML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml' as CI)
     SELECT 
     Identifier = XmlData.value('(ArrayOfCatalogItem/CatalogItem/ProductIdentifiers/CI:Identifier)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
     From
     @XmlTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://3ecompany.com/webservices/catalogitemxml' as CI)
SELECT 
    CIVersion = CI.value('@Version', 'int'),
    Identifier = PID.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM
    @XmlTable
CROSS APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('/ArrayOfCatalogItem/CatalogItem') AS XT(CI)
CROSS APPLY
    CI.nodes('CI:ProductIdentifiers/CI:Identifier') AS XT2(PID)
```

There is no *default* XML namespace, and you need to apply the `CI:` prefix to both the `<ProductIdentifiers>` as well as the `<Identifier>` nodes. Also, your sample XML is missing a closing `</FireCodeClassification>` tag ....

Comment: Mark, i might have multiple catalogItem nodes in the xml. so multiple identifers and so on. i forgot to mention it in the question.

Comment: @codebrain: and do you have multiple `<identifier>` inside a single `<catalogItem>` as well?

Comment: No only one identifier in one catalogitem. The root node ArrayofCatalogItem' will have many catalogItem node groups. For readability i added one catalogitem in the question.

Comment: Updated response to handle *multiple* `<CatalogItem>` elements

Comment: In some boolean tags, i have true\false\invalid as values, how do i cast the xquery ? writing only 'bit' as datatype returns empty resultset.

Comment: @codebrain: those might need to be treated as strings (`varchar(10)` or so)

Comment: MARK, please find this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293745/cross-apply-to-namespace-sub-nodes-returns-duplicate-records

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `*`

```
DECLARE @x XML

SELECT @x = CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\AAEWRXML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB)

SELECT @x.value('(*:ArrayOfCatalogItem/*:CatalogItem/*:ProductIdentifiers/*:Identifier)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)')
```

*If i have many catalogItems in the same what should i do?*

```
SELECT t.c.value('(*:CatalogItem/*:ProductIdentifiers/*:Identifier)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)')
FROM @x.nodes('*:ArrayOfCatalogItem') t(c)
```

Comment: It worked after adding 'as xml'  in the from clause. It works only for the first catalogitem node set in the xml. If i have many catalogItems in the same what should i do ?

Comment: still fetches me only the first identifier's value. output is only a single record. identifier[2] fetches the next catalogitem\ProductIdentifier\identifer value